# How to use mixin in meteor package

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less

I want to create package in meteor with template and style for it.

Files in folder:

- package.js
- test.html
- test.less

In package.js:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'test',
  varsion: '0.1.0'
});

Package.onUse(function(api){
  api.use('less', 'client');
  api.use('templating', 'client');

  api.addFiles('test.html', 'client');
  api.addFiels('test.less', 'client');
});
```

In test.html:

```
<template name="test">
  <a href="http://google.com/">
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
  </a>
</template>
```

In test.less:

```
@import "HOW/TO/IMPORT/MIXIN.less";

.logo {
  .img-retina("path/to/logo.png", "path/to/x2/logo.png", 119px, 41px);
  width: 119px;
  height: 41px;
}
```

And the question is:
How to add bootstrap to this package and how to import mixin from it? I can do this in application with no problem (using `nemo64:boostrap` package) but I cannot figure it out how to do this in package.

Comment: where are you trying to import from? a mixin in another package?

Comment: Yes, I want to import it from another package. But i don't want to use relative path to it.

Comment: firstly you need to `api.use` the other package then, otherwise your package will just throw an error if it's not installed. secondly, why do you not want to use a relative path? directory structure is consistent in the meteor build process.

Comment: Ok, relative path works. I have created another package with mixin and imported it in my package. But it is possible to get the same mixin in main application? In this application I cannot use relative path to file - path to packages is given from PACKAGE_DIRS export.